# How can I add values from table 1 to values in the cells of table 2 and display the result in table 2 after?

Tags: vba, excel, addition

I am looking at somewhat of a problem when trying to program a macro in Excel that is meant to add the number values from 2 tables and display the updated total in the second of the two.

I have just started learning how to program macros, so my knowledge is a little basic, but I am sure that there has to be a way to set this up in a more convenient way than what I am doing right now.

I have two tables, table 1 contains the data of the current week, which is entered manually, while table 2 is supposed to contain the total, which is calculated when clicking the macro button "Add".
I was able to fully set this up myself, using very basic code, which is why I am asking for help. At the moment the macro code is very messy and absolutely massive, I am looking at 242 declared variable values and a total of 925 lines of code.

The below is simplified and shortened, but basically how everything is working right now:
Each table contains up to 11 columns of data, with 11 rows each, so the macro is adding cells B2 to L12 to cells B29 to L39. The results are then being displayed as the total in cells B29 to L39.
The code right now:

```
Sub Add()
Dim Add As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
var1 = Range("B2").Value
var12 = Range("B29").Value
Add = var1 + var12
Range("B29").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Add
```

Like I said, this does work and does exactly what I need, but this involves a lot of code and a huge potential for mistakes, as well as hours of writing it all out. Doesn't look very good either, and is even harder to follow/work through.

Can anybody help me streamline this, make it shorter? Is there any option to sum the whole thing up in fewer lines of code, fewer arguments?

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:
As mentioned before, the code I currently have does work as intended, but I would like to cut it down volume wise. There's just too much of it and I know it is possible to do the exact same with a lot less, I just don't know how.
I have structured the code to make it a little easier to read, the first section declaring the variables, the next chunk declaring the values (separated into blocks per row in the table) and lastly the calculating action of adding table A to table B and displaying the result in table B (again, separated into blocks per row in the table).
Thank again everyone for your help.

[This is the complete code currently written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxSWU.jpg)

Comment: Only using the code you posted, this can be a single line entry `Range("B29").Value = Range("B2").Value + Range("B29").Value`.  But certainly that's not the question? You say it's a simplified model, but I'm not really sure what the question is.  Reading your post, there's a *lot* I think you left out.  You may want to have some loops or arrays, there's no reason really to use 242 variables for what I understand is some simple maths?

Comment: You may need to share a larger portion of your actual code. Was this a recorded macro? That tends to lead to lengthy code. Did you declare each cell in table as a range or something? That would produce 222 variables alone if so. 

The problem is your example code does not relate well to the info you provided so we are left to guess what exactly are those 242 variables? **Share more of your code so we can see what you are trying to do**

Comment: Let me try to give you some additional information:
Firstly, I am only just starting to learn and I am teaching myself, so my understanding of macro/VBA code is still very limited. I don't have a tutor or anything, so if you don't mind, I'd like to ask you all to dumb it down a little bit, since while I can just copy and paste your solutions, I won't understand what it is that I am using.
For instance, I have no knowledge of arrays yet, other than that they seem to be able to help sum up other parts of the code.
I will try to attach the whole code I have right now, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
Dim cell as Range
For each cell in Range("B29:L39")
    cell.Value = cell + cell.offset(-27).Value
Next
```

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `PasteSpecial()` method with `xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd` value for its *Operation* parameter

```
Range("B2:L12").Copy
Range("B29:L39").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

---

or you could use arrays

```
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant

    var1 = Range("B2:L12").Value
    var2 = Range("B29:L39").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(var1, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(var1, 2)
            var2(i, j) = var2(i, j) + var1(i, j)
        Next
    Next
    Range("B29:L39").Value = var2
```